# Don't run specified Windows applications using c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to block access to certain apps on my computer. I used the gpedit.msc tool on the computer in the category: dont run specific windows application.
I am now looking for a .netcore C # algorithm that can automatically block an app in gpedit.msc

i use this code:

```
public static class GPAwareHelper
{
    private const String REG_PATH =
       "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer";

    public static Object GetGPOverride(
       String keyName, Object configValue)
    {
        Object keyValue = null;
        RegistryKey demoKey = null;

        //if (isHKLM)
        //    // open named key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE section
        //    demoKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(REG_PATH);
        //else
        //    // open named key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER section
            demoKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(REG_PATH);

        if (demoKey != null)
        {
            // get the specified value from this key 
            keyValue = demoKey.GetValue(keyName);
            demoKey.Close();
            // check that a value was found and, if not, return `enter code here`
            // the value provided in method parameters
            if (keyValue != null)
            {

                return keyValue;
            }

            else
                return configValue;
        }
        else
        {
            // key not found, so return value provided 
            // in method parameters
            return configValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `gpedit.msc` is just an editing tool for policies. There are other tools for this, eg you could use Powershell DSC. SO what's the *actual* question?

Comment: Policies aren't just keys in a registry either, the domain/OS itself distributes them to multiple machines and applies them. Modifying the registry only modifies the local policy settings, which may be overwritten at any time. It doesn't modify the policy itself

Answer (score 0):

Group Policies are registry entries. Just write those registry entries with .netcore.

You can block certain apps by adding keys in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies
```

Here's a [good introduction](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/#:~:text=Block%20Certain%20Apps%20Through%20the,make%20changes%20to%20your%20PC.).

To write registry entries with dotnet core you have to add the package `Microsoft.Win32.Registry`

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Win32.Registry
```

Comment: That's not the same at all. Group policies can be applied to multiple machines by the OS itself. Modifying the registry with code only works with a single machine at a time

Comment: this what you meen:      RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies");
            key.SetValue("2", "AnyDesk.exe");           
            key.Close();